# Need to have multiple (same named) domain classed mapped to different database schemas

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

We are developing a grails application for a legacy database.  A problem we have reached is that we have multiple schemas in our database with the same tables but these tables may have different structures.

Is there a way to have multiple domain classes with the same name that point to different schemas and the application not "bomb" when you start it because some of the domain classes don't match the current datasource's table structure?

The user will be able to log in to different schemas at run time so we need to be able to specify which domains are mapped based off which schema they choose.

We're also open for any other suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: The application will not "bomb" until you attempt to use a domain that is not mapped correctly. As long as you don't use it - everything else should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do some metaprogramming to add attributes and methods to your domain classes right after your schema has been chosen, but it would make your code a lot more complex and difficult to debug.